# Receiving an unrecognized selector error

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, nsstring

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm attempting to pass a string from a UITableView selection into a web service and return a data set.  When I hard code the parameter, the code works fine.  When using the code below, I get this error:

> -[NSCFString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6054

```
-(void) getStateData 
{
    stateWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.**********.com/webservices.asmx/getCGbyState?"]] retain];
    //[request appendString:_Campground.country];
    NSString *country = [_Campground.country stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = (@"country=%@",country);
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [myConnection start];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the header for whatever class _Campground is?  I suspect it's `country` member may not be an NSString.

Comment: It's definitely an NSString. In the Campground.h file I have it declared with NSString *country;

Comment: I got it... It would help if I spelled Occurrences correctly... :-/ lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing 'r' in `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString`. It should be `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Lol.  I figured it out right before I saw this.

Comment: Man, how do see something like that, Eagle eyes for sure!

Comment: Well Google helped me out :) I wanted to check on the documentation for the method and see if it had anything to with the error and searched for `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString`, and the all seeing Big G said _Showing results for stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString
Search instead for stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString_ End of story :)

Comment: to easy I actually had to past one under the other and notice one was sorter than the other and double check every letter to come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "r" in `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

`occurrences` take 2 "r"

Answer (score 0):

Where is `_Campground.country` defined? It is potentially getting released before you are calling `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` on it.

You [can enable zombie objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) to see what `0x6054` actually is.